# Curving Lines Within Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Have looked at multiple resources online and can't seem to find a clear solution for my problem. I am busy creating a "Race Car Game" and am basically finished. The only problem i am having is curving a simple line. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you mean by curving a simple line? What kind of curve and what are you trying to do with it? A curved line in pygame can be as simple as using the pygame.draw.circle(surface,color,center,radius) and cropping part or most of it away. You can use trig functions to plot a curve, ect. Details please.

Comment: Perhaps if you can tell us what you have tried and why it has failed, that would be a good place to start. Try to craft a specific question and I'll see if I can help you. I don't want to speculate on what you 'might' mean because if I were to guess wrong, it would waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pygame.draw.arc()` to draw an arc *(curved line)* with a given radius:

```
pygame.draw.arc(surface, (255,255,255), [100,100,100,100], pi, pi/3)
```